# scipy.optimize curve_fit error while fitting an integral function with upper limit as independent variable

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit an integral function to my data using scipy.optimize curve_fit as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, nquad, odeint
from scipy.special import gammainc, gamma
import math
import os
import sys
import contextlib
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import string

#Global model constants, all units are CGI
day=86400.     #seconds in a day
year=3.15436e7 #seconds in a year
Msun=1.99e33   #solar mass in grams
c=2.99792458e10#speed of light
sb=5.67051e-5  #Stefan-Boltzmann constant
kms2cms=1.e5   #km/s in cm/s
r15=1.e15      #radii in units of 10^15cm
tni=8.8        #Ni-56 decay time-scale
tco=111.3      #Co-56 decay time-scale
eni=3.9e10     #Ni-56 decay specific energy generation rate
eco=6.8e9      #Co-56 decay specific energy generation rate
TH=5500.       #Hydrogen ionization temperature in K
A0=1.e14       #Radioactive decay model gamma-ray leakage parameter 
E51=1.e51      #Energy in units of 1 F.O.E. (10^51 erg)
L45=1.e45      #Luminosity in units of 10^45 erg/s
nmax=1000000   #Grid resolution for fallback accretion model 

def rad_decay_dep(t,td,r0,vej):
    return ((r0*r15/(vej*td*day*kms2cms))+t/td)*np.exp((t/td)**2  
   (2.*r0*r15*t/(vej*kms2cms*(td**2)*day)))

# Integrants for Ni-56 and Co-56 decay energy depositions

def rad_decay_int1(t,td,r0,vej):
    return rad_decay_dep(t,td,r0,vej)*np.exp(-t/tni)

def rad_decay_int2(t,td,r0,vej):
    return rad_decay_dep(t,td,r0,vej)*np.exp(-t/tco)

# Final radioactive decay luminosity integral function

def Lum_rad(x,Mni,td,r0,vej,A):
    return (2.*Mni*Msun/td)*np.exp(-((x/td)**2+(2.*r0*r15*x
    /(vej*kms2cms*(td**2)*day))))* \
    ((eni-eco)*quad(rad_decay_int1,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej))[0] +  
    eco*quad(rad_decay_int2,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej))[0])* \
    (1.-np.exp(-A*A0/(x*day)**2))

xdata, ydata = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(Lum_rad, xdata, ydata)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SLSNFit.py", line 11, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(LCmods.Lum_rad, xdata, ydata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 676, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 455, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "/Users/macbro/Desktop/LCmods.py", line 86, in Lum_rad
    ((eni-eco)*quad(rad_decay_int1,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej))[0] + eco*quad(rad_decay_int2,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej))[0])* \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 315, in quad
    points)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 364, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have tried vectorizing the function using np.vectorize but this didn't work either (I get TypeError:  is not a Python function).

The link to the input file (sn2006gy) is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng4lknaja4igwhm/sn2006gy?dl=0. I run with: >python test.py sn2006gy and I get the above error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The sample code lacks several variable definitions so I cannot run it besides that you do not show the data. The error has probably to do with an inapropriate shape of the return values of your functions. Have the functions print the shape of the results and see what you get.

Comment: My bad Christian! I copied code from two files and forgot to paste the variable definitions, they are below. I also couldn't figure out how to upload the input file. day=86400.     
year=3.15436e7 
Msun=1.99e33  
c=2.99792458e10
sb=5.67051e-5  
kms2cms=1.e5   
r15=1.e15      
tni=8.8       
tco=111.3     
eni=3.9e10     
eco=6.8e9      
TH=5500.       
A0=1.e14      
E51=1.e51      
L45=1.e45    
nmax=1000000

Comment: Please add those definitions to the code in your question rather than dumping them in the comments. You can upload the input file to an external site (e.g. filedropper) and add a link to your question.

Comment: Did you test the quad function separately with this input?

Comment: No, should I create a different function (def int():...) with just quad in it and try again? Would that make a difference?

Comment: I have updated the post with all missing definition at the link to the input file so now you can run it - still stuck so any help will be greatly appreciated! @ali_m

Comment: Check the function arguments of `quad`. You call it with an array as the upper integration limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scipy.integral.quad` cannot handle arrays as integration limit. You can define a wrapper function which accepts non-scalar limits, e.g.

```
def integral(func, a, b, args):
    ret = np.asarray([quad(func, a, q, args)[0] for q in b])
    return ret
```

and modify `Lum_rad` like this:

```
def Lum_rad(x,Mni,td,r0,vej,A):
    return (2.*Mni*Msun/td)*np.exp(-((x/td)**2+(2.*r0*r15*x
    /(vej*kms2cms*(td**2)*day))))* \
    ((eni-eco)*integral(rad_decay_int1,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej)) +  
    eco*integral(rad_decay_int2,0,x,args=(td,r0,vej)))* \
    (1.-np.exp(-A*A0/(x*day)**2))
```

The program ends after quite a while saying

`RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1200.`

Now it is up to you to fix the math.